# unicode gibberish character in html

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, unicode

I am trying to rewrite old php mysql website in codeigniter, The site is in unicode, and text in database is stored like this

```
&#2348;&#2375;&#2354;&#2366;&#2351;&#2340;&#2350;&.
```

when i pull data from database and display in html it appears like this

```
à¤¸à¤°à¥à¤µà¥‹à¤šà¥à¤šà¤•à¥‹ à
```

It is fine in old site, I am using exactly as same header as old site in html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I am banging my head how to correct text ?

Comment: What text are you expecting? And that's *not* "Unicode", those are just HTML entities.

Comment: And those HTML entities just by themselves are resolving perfectly fine to "बेलायतम". What are you doing with the text to screw it up?

Comment: could you pls guide me how to show this correctly in web page ? Thanks

Comment: What are they encoded as in your database, and what encoding are you using in your application?

Comment: I'm really having trouble understanding what you're doing to **not** make it show correctly. Please show your code.

Comment: In database collation it is latin1_swedish_ci and in application it's just php, i am just echoing content. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

Comment: The question already says "`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`"

Comment: then it is not html related issue, most likely it is problem with db charset, even if you are sure charset is right in your db structure, you might get this gibberish unicodes when using db with ORM/drivers, I usually use utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Answer (score 0):

There should be a problem, html's codes you are using are right, just in case check if you can see proper characters on this website:
http://www.unicodeblocks.com/block/Devanagari

and make sure you are using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Please double check it - use "view page source" on your page and check, maybe you used meta tag twice with different variables?

and one more...
if you are using db, please do this:

```
$mysqli->query('set character set utf8');
```